# how can I write a helper function which manage my print_help function?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a modular function helper which helps me to import to many files , and change values using an dict similar like this `help_options = {'listeners': 'show default settings','sessions': 'show sessions' ,'clear': 'clear screen','quit': 'quit'}` , but having the same output, So it is easy to maintain instead of chainging multiples fles. how can I do this?

```
def help_option():
    print("\t\033[01;32m")
    print("\tlisteners   : show default settings.")
    print("\thelp        : show default settings.")
    print("\tsessions    : show default settings.")
    print("\tclear       : clear screen.")
    print("\tquit        : quit.\033[00m")
```

```
help_options = {'listeners': 'show default settings','sessions': 'show sessions' ,'clear': 'clear screen','quit': 'quit'}

def print_help_option(option):
    found = 0
    for opt in help_options.items():
        if opt[0] == option:
            found = 1
            print("%s - %s" %(option, opt[1]))
    if not found:
        print("Error: option \'%s\' not found." %option)


print_help_option(help_options)
```

Comment: Is this for a command line tool? Then you might want to have a look at argparse or the click library.

Comment: commmd line , but how can I manage this?